L1/L2 regularization in neural nets
For linear regression, after doing L1/L2 regularization one can compute a closed form solution for the weights in nice cases. From here, one gets the intuition where:

L2 regularization shrinks weights to 0.
L1 regularization truncates weights at 0 after suitable translation; this creates sparsity of weights as a result.

(For example, this computation was done in "Elements of Statistical Learning" p.69)
Question

Do these intuition generalize to neural nets/beyond linear regression?
If yes, is there a mathematical proof behind such intuition in those cases?

As an example, is there a mathematical proof that lasso induces sparsity of weights beyond the case of linear regression?




See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136132/neural-nets-lasso-regularization?rq=1 for a related post

Thank you - just wondering, how is that post related?
